# Em Javascript, como verificar que um objeto está vazio (sem jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Pelo `jQuery`, consigo saber se um `Object` é vazio da seguinte forma:

```
$.isEmptyObject({}); // true
$.isEmptyObject(window); // false
```

Para saber se um `array` está vazio, podemos fazer da mesma forma, porém sem `jQuery` ficaria assim:

```
 var arr = []
 arr.length == 0; // True
```

Porém, e o `Object`? Como posso fazer pra saber se o mesmo está vazio?

Imaginei que poderia fazer assim:

```
Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
```

Mas pensei que não fosse muito adequado.

Quais são outras possíveis maneiras de fazer isso?

**Observação**: Gostaria que a resposta fosse sem o uso de `jQuery` e outros, mas apenas utilizando o javascript puro.

Comment: Do fonte do jQuery: isEmptyObject:function(a){var b;for(b in a)return!1;return!0}

Comment: Aposto que deu um `$.isEmptyObject.toSource()` :)

Comment: Abri com editor mesmo :)

Comment: por que não usa typeof ? e verifica se é undefined

Comment: `typeof` não vai servir. Ele retorna ria `"object"` para todos os casos (para vazios e não-vazios)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pode usar essa função:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Ele faz um loop nas propriedades do objeto e usa o método `hasOwnProperty` para verificar as propriedades do objeto, o `hasOwnProperty` é necessario se for passado um protótipo de um objeto.

Veja mais em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/328kyd6z(v=vs.94).aspx

Outro forma, com suporte a o ECMAScript 5, pode se usar assim:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

Comment: Note que, como o epx disse, no jQuery não tem `.hasOwnProperty()`, logo os resultados podem variar.

Comment: O hasOwnProperty() é realmente necessário?

Comment: Realmente, se entrar no `for` é que existe algo para iterar. Não se faz necessário o `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Sem o uso de `hasOwnProperty`, se você utilizar `prototype`, não vai funcionar.

Comment: De fato o hasOwnProperty() seria bom ter se por acaso outro código adicionou métodos de conveniência, ou atributos, direto no Object.prototype, tais adições são listadas pelo for..in, e mesmo um objeto {} não seria mais considerado vazio. Filtrar pelo hasOwnProperty() retorna que {} é vazio mesmo com manipulações no Object.prototype.

Comment: @henriquedpereira, a última forma já tem na pergunta :)

Comment: Agora que vi, mas você pode utilizar dessa forma também, não tem nada de errado.

Answer (score 8):

Uma forma de tornar essa operação rápida é utilizando também o método `toSource`.

Veja:

```
var vazio = {}

var naoVazio = {ola: 'mundo'}

function isEmptyObject(obj)
{
    return obj.toSource() === "({})";

}


isEmptyObject(vazio); // true
isEmptyObject(naoVazio); // false
```

Isso ocorre porque o `toSource` retorna essa string que é comparada na função quando chamamos ele em um objeto vazio.

Veja:

```
({}).toSource(); // "({})"
```

**Observação importante**:

> Object.prototype.toSource() is non-standard and not supported in IE:

Podemos perceber que teríamos problemas em utilizar esse método no abençoado `Internet Explorer`!

### Atualização

Conforme assinalado pela [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toSource), esse método foi depreciado [tradução livre]:

> Este recurso não é mais recomendado. Embora alguns navegadores ainda possam suportá-lo, ele pode já ter sido removido dos padrões da web relevantes, pode estar em processo de exclusão ou pode ser mantido apenas para fins de compatibilidade. Evite usá-lo e atualize o código existente, se possível;

---

### Alternativas

Alternativamente, você pode utilizar `Object.keys` ou `Object.values` em um Object. Essas funções retornarão um `Array`. Você pode checar pela propriedade `length`.

Veja:

```js
 function isEmptyObject(obj)
 {
    return !!Object.values(obj).length;    
 }
```

ou:

```js
 function isEmptyObject(obj)
 {
    return !!Object.keys(obj).length;    
 }
```

Comment: Gostei deste :)

Comment: Achei mais simples. E se precisar fazer isso só uma vez, nem precisa criar uma função :)

Comment: Tá aí uma informaçao importante para buscar e colocar na pergunta :)

Comment: Massa!.........................

Comment: Isso funciona atualmente? Testei no Chrome, Firefox e Safari e recebi erros similares a `TypeError: b.toSource is not a function`. Eu reveria a necessidade de manter esta resposta...

Answer (score 6):

Seguindo a mesma lógica da implementação do `jquery` na versão `v1.11.3` você pode verificar se ele está vazio assim:

```js
var objetoVazio = {};
var objetoContemValor = {
  "key": "valor"
};

function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  var name;
  for (name in obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isEmptyObject(objetoVazio) + ' objeto vazio');
console.log(isEmptyObject(objetoContemValor) + ' objeto com valor');
```

Se for necessário, podemos diminuir o tamanho do `for` para apenas apenas uma linha:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    var name;

    for (name in obj) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Me perdi nesse detalhe quando parei para pesquisar em meu projeto como eu fazia essa verificação, era da mesma forma dita na sua pergunta, irei reeditar com uma resposta alternativa.

Comment: Adicionei uma sugestão de `one line` no seu `for`. Ficou massa!

Answer (score 5):

Para navagadores modernos: `JSON.stringify`

```
 function isEmptyObject(obj){
        return JSON.stringify(obj) === '{}';
    }
```

### 2º Exemplo:

Assumindo que vazio seja "que não possui propriedades":

```
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

function isEmpty(obj) {

    // null é "empty"
    if (obj == null) return true;

    // Suponhamos que se tenha uma propriedade length com um valor diferente de zero
    // Essa proriedade será verdadeira
    if (obj.length > 0)    return false;
    if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

    // Caso contrário ela tem todas as sua propriedades?
    // Isto não se manipula
    // toString e valueOf são erros de enumeração no IE < 9
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

> COMO UTILIZAR?

```
isEmpty(""), // true
isEmpty([]), // true
isEmpty({}), // true
isEmpty({length: 0, custom_property: []}), // true

isEmpty("OLÁ!"), // false
isEmpty([1,2,3]), // false
isEmpty({test: 1}), // false
isEmpty({length: 3, custom_property: [1,2,3]}) // false
```

Answer (score 3):

ECMA 7+:

```
Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object
```